# Clicking multiple <span> elements with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, dropdown

I'm new to using Selenium, and I am having trouble figuring out how to click through all iterations of a specific element. To clarify, I can't even get it to click through one as it's a dropdown but is defined as an  element.

I am trying to scrape fanduel; when clicking on a specific game you are presented with a bunch of main title bets and in order to get the information I need to click the dropdowns to get to that information. There is also another drop down that states, "See More" which is a similar problem, but assuming this gets fixed I'm assuming I will be able to figure that out.

So far, I have tried to use:

```
find_element_by_class_name()
find_element_by_css_selector()
```

I have also used them in the sense of elements, and tried to loop through and click on each index of the list, but that did not work.

If there are any ideas, they would be much appreciated.

FYI: I am using beautiful soup to scrape the website for the information, I figured Selenium would be helpful making the information that isn't currently accessible, accessible.

[This image shows the dropdowns that I am trying to access, in this case the dropdown 'Win Margin'. The HTML code is shown to the left of it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zko6R.png)

This also shows that there are multiple dropdowns, varying in amount based off the game.

Comment: I suggest that you attach some sample code as well which will help us to understand the problem statement better

Comment: Can you share relevant HTML ? or page URL if possible

Comment: HTML is shared in the linked picture

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using action chains from selenium

```
menu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav")
hidden_submenu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav # submenu1")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(menu).click(hidden_submenu).perform()
```

Source: [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/action-chains-in-selenium-python/)

Comment: I have tried this with css selectors, but it didnt seem to work for me, Ill try to rerun my code and see what errors it produced when trying to use this.